# JS If Else Error

Tags: javascript

When I currently hit my submit button it changes the if else statement. The program should not do both at once.When I currently hit my submit button it changes the if else statement. The program should not do both at once.When I currently hit my submit button it changes the if else statement. The program should not do both at once.`

```
            var image_tracker='p';
            function change(){
                var image = document.getElementById('operator');
                if(image_tracker=='p'){
                image.src = "images/mult.png"
                image_tracker='m';
                    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
                    var val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value3").value);
                    var val4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value4").value);
                    var val5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value5").value);
                    var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
                    ansD.value = val1 * val2 * val3 * val4 * val5;
                }else{
                    image.src='images/plus.png'
                    image_tracker='p';
                    var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
                    ansD.value = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5;

                }
            }
    </script>
    <body>
    <div class="form">
     <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value=""/>
        <div class= value1>
        <p>You are entering the 1st Number</p>
        </div>
     <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value=""/>
        <div class= value2>
        <p>You are entering the 2nd Number</p>
        </div>
     <input type="text" id="value3" name="value3" value=""/>
        <div class= value3>
        <p>You are entering the 3rd Number</p>
        </div>
     <input type="text" id="value4" name="value4" value=""/>
        <div class= value4>
        <p>You are entering the 4th Number</p>
        </div>
     <input type="text" id="value5" name="value5" value=""/>
        <div class= value5>
        <p>You are entering the 5th Number</p>
        </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit"         onclick="javascript:change()"/>
    <br/>
    <img src="images/plus.png" alt="operator" id= "operator" onclick="change()">    
    <br/>
    <input type="label" id="answer" name="answer" value=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: Pardon my confusion... but, how come clicking on both the image AND the button performs the calculation AND changes the symbol?  Shouldn't those functions be segregated (ie, clicking the picture changes the symbol, while clicking the button performs the function)?

Anyways, I'm getting NaN as a result when I click the button.  Is that what you're getting?  I'm not sure I understand what you're getting (the exact problem).

Comment: When you ask a question and have it answered, do not go back and edit your original question - this site is for Q&A reference, and someone in the future may have the same or similar issue as you (although probably not this question because it's so specific), so leaving the original question may help others.

Comment: If you have ids `value1`, `value2`, ..., `valueX` and variables `val1`, `val2`, ..., `valN`, you are doing something horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're gonna have to work with it, but try [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HillChris1234/32rgx9uo/):

**First,** you need 2 different functions to perform the different tasks.

One to run the calculation *Note: you don't need to assign the "vals" in both if clauses, because you're using the same elements. You also don't need a `p` and or `m` variable, because you can just test the `img`'s `src` location*:

```
function calculateMe() {
    var image = document.getElementById('operator');
    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
    if (isNaN(val1)) { val1 = 0; }
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
    if (isNaN(val2)) { val2 = 0; }
    var val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value3").value);
    if (isNaN(val3)) { val3 = 0; }
    var val4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value4").value);
    if (isNaN(val4)) { val4 = 0; }
    var val5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value5").value);
    if (isNaN(val5)) { val5 = 0; }
    var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
    if(image.getAttribute("src") == "~/images/mult.png") {  
        ansD.value = val1 * val2 * val3 * val4 * val5;
    } else {
        ansD.value = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5;
    }
}
```

And one to change the image:

```
function changeIcon() {
    var image = document.getElementById('operator');
    if (image.getAttribute("src") == "~/images/mult.png") {
        image.src = "~/images/plus.png";
    } else {
        image.src = "~/images/mult.png";
    }
}
```

Then, in your HTML, just call the different functions on the individual elements:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calculateMe()"/>
<img src="~/images/plus.png" alt="operator" id= "operator" onclick="changeIcon()">
```

You'll have to play around with the image locations and the exact URL's, but that's the gist.